# Java 123, достать 1 отдельно, 2 отдельно и 3 отдельно

Tags: java

Есть int значение равно от 0 до MAX_VALUE.
Из этого значения (каким бы оно ни было), нужно достать каждую цифру и вывести в стринг формате.

String.valueOf(val) - помогает мне получить любое значение в String формате, но как достать не всё число а по отдельности, каждую последующую цифру?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Число в строку, строку в массив, каждый элемент массива это цифра.

```
int numm=123;
String[] array = String.valueOf(numm).split("");

// array[0] - 1
// array[1] - 2
// array[2] - 3
```

**UPD** 
для Java **<** 8 в массиве 0-ой элемент будет пустой.

Comment: Большое спасибо!
UPD>на 8-ой робим ;)

Comment: Да не за что, отметьте, как ответ, чтобы видно было, что вопрос решен.

Answer (score 1):

Если нужна произвольная цифра, воспользуйтесь методом `String.charAt()`:

```
int num = ...;
final String string = String.valueOf(num);
final char ch = string.charAt(...);
```

Он работает быстрее, чем `split`, так как не производит выделение места под массивы.

Если нужно доставать цифру за цифрой, этот метод можно использовать в цикле:

```
int num = ...;
final String string = String.valueOf(num);
for(int i = 0; i < string.length(); i++)
{
    final char ch = string.charAt(i);

    // ...
}
```

Comment: Upd. Этот вариант верный и тоже является правильным овтетом. Я бы сказал немного более верным.